# How to call some html file to particular part of a html page?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is there any technique to call an external .html file to the current .html file without MVC?

For example, we are using same services(links at left side as vertical accordion) in all other specific service pages.

Can we make that accordion part as separate .html file and can we call it into our each service page?

Answer (score 0):

If you use php or some other languages like that, you can do it using their built in methods like 'include' or 'require' in php.

If you want to do it with pure html, use, javascript and ajax. Set a container div in ur html page. call an ajax function to get the external html file content, insert into the container div using javascript.

Comment: could you please give me a reference??

Answer (score 0):

You can load external .html file to the current file using jQuery, try this link

http://api.jquery.com/load/

For accordion you could see this link,

http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jQuery-common-accordion

Comment: It is easy to implement using jQuery and Its supported in all web development languages like php, asp .net etc

Comment: I'm using following code as per your suggestion as following, but it is not working (load.html contains just single line plain text)

</head>   <!-- head tag end here -->
<body>
 <div id="suc"></div>
  <script>
 $("#suc").load("load.html");
  </script>
</body>

Comment: write the code using onready jquery fuction, $( document ).ready(function() {  $("#suc").load("load.html"); });

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to do this would be through **iframes**

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

But using iframes is not advised. Since you mentioned jQuery I would suggest you to look at jQueries **.load()** method

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery ajax load API for this,

```
$( "#result" ).load( "test.html" );
```

This will load contents in `test.html` into the element with id `#result` in your main page.

Refer [.load() API](http://api.jquery.com/load/)